# Are python 'switches' (dict) supposed to call every func inside?

Tags: python, switch-statement

I was trying to code something with the use of a python switch, simulated in a dict as suggested in: [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python) [Second answer, by Nick]

When I tested, for some reason all the functions inside were being called, tried a simple code to see what was wrong and the problem repeated. See:

```
def switch(f):
    print('Switch got: ', f)
    var = {
        1: func1(),
        2: func2(),
        3: func3()
        }.get(f,False)
    return var

def func3():
    fb = 'Func3 called'
    print(fb)
    return fb

def func1():
    rsp = 'Func1 called'
    print(rsp)
    return rsp

def func2():
    rsp = 'Func2 called'
    print(rsp)
    return rsp

var = switch(1)
print(var)
```

My expected return was just:

```
Switch got:  1
Func1 called
```

Instead i got:

```
Switch got:  1
Func1 called
Func2 called
Func3 called
Func1 called
```

What I got from it is that python seems to run every func inside the dict before calling the proper key (1 in the example).

**Is this the expected behavior in Python?**

**Is there a way around, where only the function that corresponds to the key is called?**

Comment: change to  `def switch(f):
    print('Switch got: ', f)
    func = {
        1: func1,
        2: func2,
        3: func3
        }.get(f)
    return func() if func is not None else False`

Comment: [The third answer on that page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60215/102441) looks like exactly what you need

Comment: @Eric Not sure I could use lambda, because the actual code is more complex than the one posted. But I get your point. Thanks

Comment: "for some reason all the functions inside were being called" because *you are explicitly calling them*

Comment: @ZeCarioca: `lambda: my_complex_code()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this the expected behavior in Python?

Yes.

> Is there a way around, where only the function that corresponds to the key is called?

Don't actually call the functions when you create your dispatch dict:

```
def switch(k):
    print('Switch got: ', k)
    func = {
        1: func1,
        2: func2,
        3: func3,
    }.get(k, bool)
    var = func()
    return var
```

Comment: I think having it return the result of calling type `bool` as the default is at best obscure.

Answer (score 1):

The act of initializing that dictionary when the function 'switch' is called also calls the functions. Try something like this,

```
def switch(f):
    print('Switch got: ', f)
    var = {
        1: func1,
        2: func2,
        3: func3
        }.get(f,False)
    if not var:
      return false
    return var()
```